# Getting access to network server

Tags: samba, permissions

I logon to my server successfully and can transfer files off the server to my desktop. But I can't put any files back. I get a "permission denied" error. I know I have full access to the network server because on a mac after I mount the server, I can do whatever I want. How do I change permissions?

It is an SMB server. I am logged in as a user with administrator privileges. When I check for permissions in Nautilus, it says it can't determine them.

Thanks.

Comment: More information is needed: How do you access the server? SFTP, Samba, ... ? Which users do the files belong to and what are the permissions? As which user are you accessing the files?

Comment: It is an SMB server. I am logged in as a user with administrator privileges. 
When I check for permissions in Nautilus, it says it can't determine them. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @LawrenceGoodman I've added your comment information into your question - as you try to figure out your problem edit your question directly so that the information doesn't get buried in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're accessing the samba share by mounting it as a cifs file system. Try to set the [uid and gid parameters for mount](http://gertranssmb3.berlios.de/output/mount.cifs.8.html) to your uid and gid. Only the user id is used for identification when accessing a samba share, not the user name. If your uid on your desktop is different from the uid on the server the server does not recognize that you're the right user.